# Index-Match with filtering and multiple selection (2 columns)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Can you please help regarding this formula in Excel 2007:

`INDEX('MappFile'!F:F &"","" & 'MappFile'!G:G, MATCH(E:E,IF('MappFile'!E:E="Prod",('MappFile'!C:C)),FALSE))`

The intention/purpose is the following:
'To match column **E** from main file
'With column **C** from 'Mapping File'
'Based on this take **F & G** from 'MappFile'
'filtering only the rows where column **E** from 'MappFile' = Prod

Thank you in advance!

For Vasim: this is a variant that works (syntaically) but doesn't grant the desired result:

`=INDEX('MappFile'!F:F, MATCH(E:E,IF('MappFile'!E:E="Prod",('MappFile'!C:C)),FALSE))`

In my example, the IF is intended to do the filtering but it must probably be done differently

Comment: Nothing seems to be right in your formula...maybe you can post some spreadsheet with detailed information....

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You should make an extra column that filters with your if, and then use that column as the comparison array.